# How to get file extension from a uri of Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have file uri {s3://video-seven-test/file_name.mp4} how do I get the extension from this uri?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php to parse the URL to get the proper path and http://php.net/pathinfo to get the extension from the path

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = file_load($fid);
$path = drupal_realpath($file->uri);
$parts = pathinfo($path);
$extension = $parts['extension'];
```

thanks to [nmc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/727439/nmc)